# ./my/path/ not recognized as directory in hosting server

Tags: php, directory, codeigniter-2, captcha

I'am using codeigniter captcha helper. I have followed the [manual](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/captcha_helper.html) and it's working well in local server. But when i move it to hosting server it's not working anymore. I have trace the problem and found that my captcha directory path **"./captcha/"** was not recognized as a directory. What's wrong with that? 
As like as on my local server **"./"** should point to my root directory. Am i wrong?

here is my captcha function:

```
protected function captcha($font_size,$width,$height,$exp)
    {
        $vals = array(
            'img_path'   => './captcha/',
            'img_url'    => base_url().'/captcha/',
            'font_path'  => './fonts/AntykwaBold.ttf',
            'font_size'  => $font_size,
            'img_width' => $width,
            'img_height' => $height,
            'expiration' => $exp
        );

        if ($cap = create_captcha($vals)){
            $data = array(
                'captcha_time'  => $cap['time'],
                'ip_address'    => $this->input->ip_address(),
                'word'              => ($cap['word'])
            );
            $query = $this->db->insert_string('captcha', $data);
            $this->db->query($query);
            return $cap;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically, the ./ is unnecessary, at least in standard directory format. "/captcha" should point to your captcha directory. Try that and see if it works. 
Good luck.